# Problems Adding aceoledb.dll as a reference in VB 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ms-access

I'm using VB2010 and Access.

My connection string works absolutely fine

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\Database1.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
```

I have the Access Database Engine installed on my machine and I'm trying to add the ACEOLEDB.DLL to my references but I get the following error

[image]

The file exists but I can't add it. I'm assuming by adding the dll it will rule out the need for the end user not to install the Access Database Engine??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want your application to be able to use `System.Data.OleDb` objects with the `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` provider then you don't need to add any references to your VB.NET project. The ACE OLEDB provider is registered with Windows when the Access Database Engine is installed.

> I'm assuming by adding the dll it will rule out the need for the end user not to install the Access Database Engine?

That is incorrect. The appropriate version<sup>*</sup> of the Access Database Engine will still need to be installed on each machine where your application will be running.

<sup>*</sup> (That is, 32-bit or 64-bit, the same as the "bitness" of your application.)